how extract the data from the anylogic simulation model in the json format
i wanted to extract the data from anylogic simulation model in the Json format and use it in the unity with help of API and display simulation in the unity
Anyone please helps me here To extract data from an AnyLogic simulation model in JSON format

find a java package that converts data into json format and use that. Or write your own code to produce a json file...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want to save any Java class as a JSON object you can use the jackson-databind library.
Here is such an example I created using that library
public static void exportToJSON(Object obj, String filename) {
        
        // Object from the Jackson lib which has the object serialization features
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        try {
            mapper.writeValue(new File(filename), obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

For quick video see here - https://youtube.com/shorts/408RIjwwG5Y
Or a model on the ANyLogic cloud with this exact example https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/468d7eba-d462-44c8-b41c-3042888a7345?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL
